# Why won't my string hold spaces?

Tags: java, string, space

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestEditor {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String input;
        char[] words = new char[100];
        int choice=0;
        int start=0;
        int end=0;
        LineEditor myEditor = new LineEditor();
        LineEditor myEditor2 = new LineEditor();
        String input2 = null;
        System.out.println("+++++++ LineEditor starts... +++++++\n");
        System.out.println("* Write the text you want (maximum length: 100): ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = in.next();
        while(input.length()>100){
            System.out.println("* Operation failed: You exceeded the maximum length.");
            System.out.println("* Write the text you want (maximum length: 100): ");
            input = in.next();
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------------------\n");
        do{
            System.out.println("*Choose the menu:\n1. Insert\n2. Delete\n3. Replace\n4. Quit");
            choice=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\n");
            if(choice==1){
                System.out.println("* Enter the starting position:");
                start = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("* Enter the text you want to replace:");
                input2=in.next();
                myEditor.insert(input, start, input2);
            }
            if(choice ==2){
                System.out.println("* Enter the starting and ending position for deletion.");
                start=in.nextInt();
                end=in.nextInt();
                myEditor.delete_text(input, start,end);
            }
            if(choice==3){
                System.out.println("* Enter the starting and ending position for insertion.");
                start=in.nextInt();
                end=in.nextInt();
                System.out.println("* Enter the text you want to replace:");
                input2=in.next();
                myEditor.replace(input, input2, start, end);
            }
        }while(choice !=4);
        System.out.println("Good Bye!");
    }
    }


    public class LineEditor {
    private static char [] text;
    private static char [] text2;


    public LineEditor(){
        text=new char[100];
        text2=new char[100];
    }

    public void insert(String input, int start, String input2){
        start = start-1;
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
            text[i]=input.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<input2.length();i++){
            text2[i]=input2.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=start; i<input.length();i++){
            text[i]=text[i+start];
        }
        for(int i=start; i<input.length();i++){
            text[i]=text2[j];
            j++;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<text.length;i++){
            System.out.print(text[i]);
        }

    }
    public void delete_text(String input, int start, int end){
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
            text[i]=input.charAt(i);
        }
        start=start-1;
        int num = end-start;
        for(int i=start; i<end;i++){
            text[i]=text[i+num];
        }
        for(int i=end;i<text.length;i++){
            if((i+end)<100){
                text[i]=text[i+end];
            }else{
                text[i]=text[i-end];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<text.length;i++){
            System.out.print(text[i]);
        }
    }
    public void replace(String input, String input2, int start, int end){
        start = start-1;
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
            text[i]=input.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<input2.length();i++){
            text2[i]=input2.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=start; i<input.length();i++){
            text[i]=text[i+start];
        }
        for(int i=start; i<input.length();i++){
            text[i]=text2[j];
            j++;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<text.length;i++){
            System.out.print(text[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at TestEditor.main(TestEditor.java:29)
```

So those are my two classes and I keep getting this error when I put a space in my initial input. The error doesn't even happen when I transfer it to an array. Can someone shed some light? Also here is a [link for the exact prompt](https://wiki.ittc.ku.edu/ittc/EECS168%3aHomework4) if you would like to look at it.

Comment: You keep getting what error?

Comment: This aint pastebin.con

Comment: Yeah I do. Each time I put a space in the middle of the input. If I do " input" or "input " it works fine. But just in the middle.

Comment: `in.next()` only gets one word of input.  You probably want to use something different to get your text; otherwise when you do `in.nextInt()`, the `Scanner` probably won't be looking at an integer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just changed it to 'in.nextLine()' and it worked like a charm. Thank you!!!!

Comment: No it really didn't help you much.  You'll have a problem when you next do `nextLine()`, because `nextInt()` won't take the newline character after the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `in.next()`, try using `in.nextLine()` instead. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Word of caution, you may encounter an event where when you come to entering a numerical value, it will error out or not take input until you try again. You may have to clear the buffer by putting `in.nextLine()` before `myVariable = in.nextInt()`. But only do this if you encounter such an error.

Comment: No, actually you want the additional `nextLine()` to go AFTER each call to `nextInt()`; otherwise the following call to `nextLine()` will return no data, as explained in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `next()` to `nextLine()`

`next()` takes space as delimiter, so when you enter e.g. "Hello test", it take "Hello" only as first input, remaining string goes as input for next scanner call ( in your case this is `choice=in.nextInt();`) and it will fail to parse string to int.

Answer (score 0):

From   [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html):

```
  public class InputMismatchException
    extends NoSuchElementException
```

Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

Change `next()` to `nextLine()`

`next()` can read the input only till the space. It can't read two words separated by space. Also, `next()` places the cursor in the same line after reading the input.

`nextLine()` reads input including space between the words (that is, it reads till the end of line \n). Once the input is read, `nextLine()` positions the cursor in the next line.

Use the `nextLine()` method to read all of what is on the current line. It is possible for the current line to only have a newline character which would return an empty string.